# What effect does it have if I use `--enable-azure-rbac` and `--aad-admin-group-object-ids` at the same time

Tags: azure, azure-aks

I have an existing AKS cluster that I created using the Azure CLI without enabled Azure RBAC and adding an admin group id with the following command

```
az aks create `
--name test `
--resource-group $rg `
--node-count 3 `
--kubernetes-version "1.28.3" `
--node-vm-size "Standard_D2s_v3" `
--enable-cluster-autoscaler `
--min-count 3 `
--max-count 5 `
--enable-managed-identity `
--enable-aad `
--aad-admin-group-object-ids $groupid `
--aad-tenant-id $tenantid
```

I later decided to enable RBAC (I have the preview extension enabled in Azure CLI and hence I am able to do that) using `az aks update -g $rg -n test --enable-azure-rbac`. This enabled the RBAC but I can see the returned json response, that `aadProfile.adminGroupObjectIDs` still has my previous admin group id.

```json
{
  "aadProfile": {
    "adminGroupObjectIDs": [
      "some-id-here"
    ],
    "adminUsers": null,
...
}
```

I have tried creating a fresh cluster having both `--aad-admin-group-object-ids` and `--enable-azure-rbac` flags and the cluster created just fine with a similar json response as above. I also tried creating a fresh cluster with only `--enable-azure-rbac` and that also successfully created the cluster with the json response having `"adminGroupObjectIDs": null`.

I am not sure what purpose the `--aad-admin-group-object-ids` flag serves when using the `--enable-azure-rbac`. Some insights would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*When you create an AKS cluster with Azure Active Directory (which is now called as Entra ID) integration using `--aad-admin-group-object-ids`, you're specifying the AAD group whose members should be granted admin permissions on the AKS cluster.*

If you *later enable Azure RBAC for Kubernetes authorization on the cluster* with `--enable-azure-rbac`, it sets up the Azure RBAC authorization model in addition to the Kubernetes role-based access control.

**Having both** `--aad-admin-group-object-ids` and `--enable-azure-rbac` means:

1. Members of the AAD group specified in `--aad-admin-group-object-ids` will have admin permissions on the AKS cluster.
2. Azure RBAC will also be used to control access to Kubernetes resources based on Azure roles and permissions.

So, the AAD group specified during cluster creation is still recognized as having admin rights, but now you can further refine and manage user permissions using Azure roles. This combination allows for more granular access control and integrates the cluster's access management with your overall Azure environment.

If `adminGroupObjectIDs` is `null`, it means no specific AAD group has been designated for admin rights, and access is controlled solely through Azure RBAC roles. Users and groups would need to be assigned roles like "Azure Kubernetes Service RBAC Cluster Admin" or "Azure Kubernetes Service RBAC Writer" to access the AKS resources.

It's important to note that enabling Azure RBAC does not remove previously granted permissions through `--aad-admin-group-object-ids`. Instead, it layers the Azure RBAC model on top of the existing Kubernetes RBAC settings.

***Let's go through an example to support the above explanation-***

First, create an AKS cluster with AAD integration by specifying a group object ID. Members of this AAD group will have admin rights on the AKS cluster.

```
az aks create `
--name <clustername> `
--resource-group $rg `
--node-count 3 `
--kubernetes-version "1.27.7" `
--node-vm-size "Standard_D2s_v3" `
--enable-cluster-autoscaler `
--min-count 3 `
--max-count 5 `
--enable-managed-identity `
--enable-aad `
--aad-admin-group-object-ids $groupid `
--aad-tenant-id $tenantid
```

After the cluster is created, members of the specified AAD group should have admin rights on the cluster. You can validate this by logging in as a member and running a command that requires admin privileges:

`az aks get-credentials --resource-group MyResourceGroupname --name <ClusterName> --admin kubectl get nodes`
[image]

Next, update the cluster to use Azure RBAC for Kubernetes authorization.

```
az aks update \
  --resource-group ResourceGroupName \
  --name ClusterName \
  --enable-azure-rbac
```

[image]

Check that Azure RBAC is enabled by inspecting the AKS cluster's properties:
`az aks show \ --resource-group ResourceGroupName \ --name ClusterName \ --query "aadProfile"`
[image]

This shows `enableAzureRBAC: true` in the output, confirming that Azure RBAC has been enabled for the AKS cluster.

Assign Azure RBAC roles to control access to the AKS cluster:

```
az role assignment create \
  --assignee <User-Principal-Name> \
  --role "Azure Kubernetes Service RBAC Admin" \
  --scope $(az aks show --resource-group ResourceGroupName --name ClusterName --query id -o tsv)
```

This principal name you will find under your Entra ID (AD) under users-> your name or whomever you want to assign

[image]

Log in as the user to whom you assigned the role, and validate that they have access as per the role assigned:
`az login`
`kubectl get pods`
[image]

In this example:

- You created an AKS cluster with AAD integration and assigned a group admin rights via `--aad-admin-group-object-ids`.
- After enabling Azure RBAC, you managed access through Azure roles.
- The AAD group specified during cluster creation still had admin rights.
- Additional users or groups could be given specific roles using Azure RBAC.

This illustrates the layered approach to access control, where both AAD group memberships and Azure RBAC roles can govern access to AKS resources.

Reference Doc:
[MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/overview)
[MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/enable-authentication-microsoft-entra-id)
[MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/azure-ad-rbac?tabs=portal)

Comment: Great explanation, would you be able to tell if keeping both Azure RBAC and Kubernetes RBAC is a bad practice or not?

Comment: In MS Docs, there is no indication that keeping both Azure RBAC and Kubernetes RBAC is a bad practice. In fact, Azure RBAC is recommended for the Azure Key Vault data plane, while Kubernetes RBAC provides granular filtering of user actions for Kubernetes resources within your cluster. Both use role-based access control (RBAC) and can be used together to provide fine-grained access management for Azure resources and Kubernetes resources respectively.